# parallel processing in bat file for loop

Tags: batch-file

I want a batch file to do parallel processing. I have a storedprocedure which returns 1000+ records(has unique rowid column along with other info). Iterating though each row works fine. However, it takes long time to complete 1000 loops. Is there a way to run two loops parallel without overlapping or having to maintain separate batch files. Can this be accomplished by having one .bat file.

WORKING CODE:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions
set ListFile=%TEMP%\StudentList.tmp
Set varServerPath=http://xyz/ReportServer

sqlcmd -Q "exec dbo.Storedproc_StudentList" -S ServerName -d DatabaseName >"%ListFile%" 2>nul

if exist "%ListFile%" (
   for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4 skip=2 delims=', " %%A in ("%ListFile%") do (
        echo Processing StudentID %%A and SubjectID %%B ...
        if not exist "%%D" mkdir "%%D"
        rs -i C:\ReportRender\Student.rss -s%varServerPath% -e Exec2005 -v StudentID="%%A" -v SubjectID="%%B" -v vOutputFilePath="%%C"  -v vReportPath="/Student Reports/ReportName.rdl" -l 900 
    )
del "%ListFile%"
)
exit
```

I tried doing something like having two for loops one from 1 to 200 and other from 201 to 400 and so on....but seems like i'm on the wrong track. It doesn't work, Please suggest.

```
    @echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions
set ListFile=%TEMP%\StudentList.tmp
Set varServerPath=http://xyz/ReportServer

sqlcmd -Q "exec dbo.Storedproc_StudentList" -S ServerName -d DatabaseName >"%ListFile%" 2>nul

if exist "%ListFile%" (
    for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4 skip=2 delims=', " %%A in ("%ListFile%") do (

            for /L %%A in(1,1,200) do (
            echo Processing StudentID %%A and SubjectID %%B ...
            if not exist "%%D" mkdir "%%D"
            rs -i C:\ReportRender\Student.rss -s%varServerPath% -e Exec2005 -v StudentID="%%A" -v SubjectID="%%B" -v vOutputFilePath="%%C"  -v vReportPath="/Student Reports/ReportName.rdl" -l 900 
            )

            for /L %%A in(201,1,400) do (
            echo Processing StudentID %%A and SubjectID %%B ...
            if not exist "%%D" mkdir "%%D"
            rs -i C:\ReportRender\Student.rss -s%varServerPath% -e Exec2005 -v StudentID="%%A" -v SubjectID="%%B" -v vOutputFilePath="%%C"  -v vReportPath="/Student Reports/ReportName.rdl" -l 900 
            )

    )
del "%ListFile%"
)
exit
```

Thanks,

Comment: Please reformat the code so that become more readable...

Comment: Using BAT for parallel processing is like digging a tunnel with a spoon. It's definitely the wrong tool.

Comment: @MichaelS: I do not agree. I invite you to post a solution to this problem using the tool you want that be simpler than the Batch file solution below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is wrong. You are executing a `for /L %%A in (1,1,200) ...` and a `for /L %%A in (201,1,400) ...` *for each record* in the %ListFile%. You need to *distribute the records* in the %ListFile% into the two parallel processes. Although this can be done in groups of 200 records, it is much simpler to do that one-by-one. Also, the only way to have parallel processes in a Batch file is via `start` command or using a `|` pipe. In this case you want to distribute several *input records* that will be read (and processed) by two "output processes", so the pipe approach is simpler.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

if "%1" neq "" goto %1

set ListFile=%TEMP%\StudentList.tmp
Set varServerPath=http://xyz/ReportServer

sqlcmd -Q "exec dbo.Storedproc_StudentList" -S ServerName -d DatabaseName >"%ListFile%" 2>nul

if not exist "%ListFile%" exit

set numProcs=2
( "%~F0" Input  |  "%~F0" Output ) 2>&1  |  "%~F0" Output
del "%ListFile%"
exit


:Input
set i=0
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4 skip=2 delims=', " %%A in ("%ListFile%") do (
   set /A i+=1, proc=i%%numProcs
   if !proc! equ 1 (
      echo %%A %%B %%C %%D
   ) else (
      >&2 echo %%A %%B %%C %%D
   )
)
exit /B


:Output
for /F "tokens=1-4" %%A in ('findstr "^"') do (
   echo Processing StudentID %%A and SubjectID %%B ...
   if not exist "%%D" mkdir "%%D"
   rs -i C:\ReportRender\Student.rss -s%varServerPath% -e Exec2005 -v StudentID="%%A" -v SubjectID="%%B" -v vOutputFilePath="%%C"  -v vReportPath="/Student Reports/ReportName.rdl" -l 900 
)
exit /B
```

- The `:Input` part just distribute the "%ListFile%" records to Stdout (channel 1) and Stderr (channel 2), one by one.
- The `:Output` part just take the `%%A %%B %%C %%D` values sent by `:Input` part and process they in the usual way; the input data is read from Stdin via `findstr` command.
- The `:Input` and `:Output` parts could be in separate Batch files, but they are included in the same file and selected via a parameter and the `if "%1" neq "" goto %1` command placed at beginning.
- The most interesting code is the pipeline that run the 3 processes in parallel. The :Input part run and its Stdout output is feed into the first :Output process. The Stderr output (channel 2) of :Input part is redirected into Stdin via the `2>&1`, so this output is feed into the second :Output process.

This method may also be used for more than two output parallel processes; you just need to add more similar parts changing the number 2 for 3, etc. For example, with three output processes the pipeline should be this one:

```
( ( "%~F0" Input  |  "%~F0" Output ) 2>&1  |  "%~F0" Output ) 3>&1  |  "%~F0" Output
```

However, it is *very important* that you note that this method does **NOT** necessarily imply that the whole process will run faster! This point depends on several factors, like the number of CPU cores and the speed/buffers of the disk drive. Just a test can answer this question...

Post the result, please.

Comment: Thank you so very much. Very useful script. I ran the script and worked fine. But it took the same time. As you mentioned, this might be because I was running it in my local machine which one core. It will have a better performance once deployed to a better server. Thanks Again :)